# Problems with updating state in Next.js app with search function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have been having problems the last little while during some project I am working on, and was hoping someone could help clear up some problems I have. I am fairly new to Next.js, and React as a whole, I've been self teaching myself. Regardless, I have a search function in my program that utilizes fuse.js, the search WORKS, BUT the problem comes along AFTER I have performed the search, and want to clear out the search bar, after I type in whatever I want into the search bar, the state only updates to what was typed in, so when I backspace, it doesn't update the state to show the entire data set. I will post my code here for some assistance.

````
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import StudentProfiles from '../components/studentProfiles'
import SearchBar from '../components/searchbar'
import Fuse from 'fuse.js'

export default function Home() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("")
    const json = await res.json()
    setData(json.students)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();
  }, []);

  const searchData = (pattern) => {
    if (!pattern) {
      setData(data);
      return;
    }

    const fuse = new Fuse(data, {
      keys: ["firstName", "lastName"],
    });

    const result = fuse.search(pattern);
    const matches = [];
    if (!result.length) {
      setData([]);
    } else {
      result.forEach(({item}) => {
        matches.push(item);
      });
      setData(matches);
    }
  };

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="dataHolder"> 
          <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search by name"
            onChange={(e) => searchData(e.target.value)}
        />      
          {data.map((item) => (
            <StudentProfiles {...item} key={new Date().valueOf() + "-" + item.id}/>
        ))}
        </div>

      <style jsx>
        {`
          html {
            background-color: black;
          }
          .wrapper{
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
            overscroll-behavior: contain;
          }

          .dataHolder {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 65%;
            height: 75%;
            background-color: white;
            position: fixed;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </div>
  )
} 

// Home.getIntialProps = async (ctx) => {
//   const res = await fetch("")
//   const json = await res.json()
//   return {items: json.students}
// }```
````

Comment: So, lets say I want to search for a "Clarke", I Clarke shows up in the results, but if I wanted to search for another student, only Clarke will show up because that's what the "data" state is set to, if that makes sense? So if I typed in a name that doesn't exist, nothing would show up, and I would have to reload the page for the data set to come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You have only one `data` state that is only ever reduced through searching/filtering, so when you backspace and assume more results should be added back in, they can't since previous `setData` calls wiped them out.

## Solution

Use two pieces of state, one to represent the source of truth and the second for search results. Always use the source of truth for searching, update the results.

```
export default function Home() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]); // <-- results state

  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("");
    const json = await res.json();
    setData(json.students);
    setResults(json.students); // <-- seed the results state
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();
  }, []);

  const searchData = (pattern) => {
    if (!pattern) {
      setResults(data); // <-- reset to full data state
      return;
    }

    const fuse = new Fuse(data, { // <-- use data state 
      keys: ["firstName", "lastName"],
    });

    const result = fuse.search(pattern);
    const matches = [];
    if (!result.length) {
      setResults(data); // <-- reset to full data state
    } else {
      result.forEach(({item}) => {
        matches.push(item);
      });
      setResults(matches); // <-- update results state
    }
  };

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="dataHolder"> 
          <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search by name"
            onChange={(e) => searchData(e.target.value)}
        />      
          {results.map((item) => ( // <-- render from results state
            <StudentProfiles {...item} key={new Date().valueOf() + "-" + item.id}/>
        ))}
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Awesome! The search function works as intended! The only problem now is with using this approach, on the initial load of the page, none of the data is displayed, but once I start typing it shows up, and vice versa as I delete the search the entire dataset is displayed, is there possibly a way to have the dataset appear on the initial load as well?

Comment: @lhunter50 Sure, you can initialize both `data` and `results` in the `useEffect` hook. I suppose also to reset to `data` instead of `[]` when no results are found would work for the second issue. Updated my answer, hopefully I understood your new issue/question.

Comment: Oh wow! It works perfect! Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I shall do that, once I figure out how to accept it as the answer, I have also upvoted but I do not have enough rep yet!